# wxPython ListCtrl Help

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I'm using a ListCtrl and it is populated with items on the fly, when an item is "Activated"(Double Click/Enter) it calls a function.

```
    def onClick(self, event):
```

How do I find out which item was clicked in the List since they don't have pre-set IDs? Is the String passed to the function as part of self or event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `event.GetText()` or `event.GetItem().<manipulate your item here>`; here is [`wx.ListEvent`](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Events/wx.ListEvent.html) documentation.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the website =D I've had trouble finding good documentation.

Comment: For wxPython docs, check this out: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/05/wxpython-documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are probably binding the ListCtrl with the event, the ListCtrl item gets passed inside the event;

```
list = event.GetEventObject()
selected_string = list.GetStringSelection()
```

So now you have all ListCtrl methods available inside the event handler.

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Event-class.html

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html