# wxPython ListCtrl OnClick Event

Tags: events, wxpython, call, listctrl, event-binding

So, I have a wxPython ListCtrl which contains rows of data. How can I make an event that calls a function, with the row contents, when one of the rows if clicked on?

Comment: See the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531207/wxpython-listctrl-help

Comment: @Stephen-Terry Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question entirely; how can I call the function in the first place? Those replies are about how to get the information from the event, once the function has been called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `Bind` function to bind a method to an event.  For example,

```
import wx

class MainWidget(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(parent=self)
        for i,j in enumerate('abcdef'):
            self.list.InsertStringItem(i,j)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnClick, self.list)

        self.Layout()

    def OnClick(self, event):
        print event.GetText()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MainWidget(None, "ListCtrl Test")
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This app will print the item in the ListCtrl that is activated (by pressing enter or double-clicking).  If you just want to catch a single click event, you could use `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`.

The important point is that the `Bind` function specifies the method to be called when a particular event happens.  See the section in the wxPython Getting Started guide on [event handling](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Event_handling).  Also see the docs on [ListCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxlistctrl.html) for the events that widget uses.